# Why does the Community user/bot have the Supporter badge?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

Just check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1?tab=recent#sort-top

Support is supposed to be rewarded for your first upvote. Why would Community upvote somehing?

Comment: No offense, but is this even relevant?

Comment: Can somebody please edit the title to read, "Is Community SkyNet?"

Comment: It is about stackoverflow, isn't it? It seemed odd that a bot supposed to be responsible for all the downvotes blah blah... would have upvotes...

Comment: Perhaps I should have avoided the comical remark at the end... Removing it right now.

Comment: @Ian: that question can, and has, come up, and I think that both that and this question are perfectly valid for Meta

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose all questions can have their place.

Comment: The real question I have to ask is: "Who cares?" Are you in competition with the community user or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you look, the Community User [owns 70 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1?tab=stats#sort-top), so it's not a bug. The reason why it was recently awarded is because Community owns the upvotes on migrated questions, a fairly new feature.